# Javascript not working in Google Chrome on cell phones

Tags: javascript

Google Chrome on an iPhone and Android cell phone won't execute javascript code in an external file.  The same website works fine with Firefox and Edge.  All 3 browsers work fine on my desktop computer.

What is causing this strange oddity?

The function called occurs in a form element onBlur event.